# Download Excel File from a Website - CSV/MySql

Tags: php, mysql, excel, csv, notepad++

First, sorry my english isn't very good.

I have a problem, when I download an Excel File from a Website(direct download) it works on Windows but it isn't working on MAC. 
I get the Names and Prenames etc. from a Mysql database.

The german `"ä - ü - ö"` are not properly converted on MAC.

How can I convert this? Do you know what I mean?

I work with Notepad++.
Programming Language is PHP
Excel version : 2010.

Comment: please try this script http://www.2my4edge.com/2013/07/file-download-coding-using-php-and-mysql.html

Answer (score 0):

From what you told I suppose you have a PHP script that generates a CSV file with data from your database.

So this sounds like a typical *encoding/charset* problem to me. You have to define in which encoding you want to store your texts in the database. That's in the most common case `UTF-8` these days. For german texts (suppose thats the language because of the umlauts) you could also use `ISO-8859-15` encoding.

It's just a guess but in your case I think maybe you did not specify how the browser should interpret the received CSV file.

You normally tell the browser about it in a http header.

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="ISO-8859-15"
```

or whatever charset you are using (Maybe `"UTF-8"` instead).

Maybe the [PHP header function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) docu helps you setting the http header.
It's also possible to define the charset in the HTML page. But I think in your case you let the PHP script sends the CSV file and not HTML. But for the record, setting the charset in HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```